# How to add framework file to git

Tags: git, macos

Is there a way to instruct git to consider a ".framework" file as a normal file?
I don't want to see any inner details about the framework(all the files/folder that it contains) in my repository.

I added a screenshot from sourcetree to visualize my problem, I want to see only MPCheckout.framework file, but it looks like git treat this file as a folder

[image]

Comment: What is a .framework file ? Why don't you just add and commit it to git as any "normal" file ? What is the problem you face when you do it ?

Comment: @Zeitounator 10x, I added a screenshot

Comment: That does not tell us what it looks like when you add/commit it to git. From what I understand quickly, it is only some sort of compressed file that should be treated as binary. If I got it correctly, have a look at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes. Meanwhile be extra careful versioning binary data in git, especially if it changes often. In most of cases it is a bad idea.

Comment: A framework is, in fact, a folder, not a file, so you can't make git handle it as a file.

Comment: @Zeitounator I guess this is simply a folder that macos tries to present it as a file, because "*.framework binary" in .gitattributes did not help me

Comment: @KamenDobrev it is a folder

Comment: Well if it is a folder, you just have to version the files in there as "normal" files.

Comment: Then my question will be "how to treat a folder as a single file" which sounds awkward :)

Comment: Unlike a .app, a .framework is not presented as a file.  It has a different icon than a normal folder, but double-clicking opens it to reveal its contents, and it shows a disclosure triangle in Finder's list view.